# Limit the word count in the post title

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, title, wp-title

Is there a way to limit the word count of the post title?

I searched over the internet but found nothing.

All I know is, only the content of the post can be limited or excerpted.

Answer (score 8):

simply use this where ever you want to display your title with limited words

```
<?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 5 ); ?>
```

replace number 5 in above code with whatever number of words you need to display.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

If continue sign "..." needed at end of title

```
<?php
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 10, '...' );
?>
```

If continue sign "..." not needed at end of title

```
<?php
    echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 10 );
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in function for that: [`wp_trim_words()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_trim_words/).

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_75691_trim_words' );

function wpse_75691_trim_words( $title )
{
    // limit to ten words
    return wp_trim_words( $title, 10, '' );
}
```

If you want to trim the words depending on certain properties of the post, ask WP to [pass the post ID](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) to your callback. Here is an example for filtering by post type. But you can also check for associated terms, post age or author, and even post meta.

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_75691_trim_words_by_post_type', 10, 2 );

function wpse_75691_trim_words_by_post_type( $title, $post_id )
{

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );

    if ( 'product' !== $post_type )
        return $title;

    // limit to ten words
    return wp_trim_words( $title, 10, '' );
}
```

Comment: How can this be applied to a specific post type only?

Comment: Found it... 

`add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_75691_trim_words' );

function wpse_75691_trim_words( $title )
{
    $cur_pt = get_post_type();
    if( 'some_post_type' == $cur_pt ) {   // limit to ten words
     return wp_trim_words( $title, 10, '' );
    } else {
     return $title;
    }
}`

Comment: @Pete See my update. I added an example for how to use the post object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function limit_word_count($title) {
    $len = 5; //change this to the number of words
    if (str_word_count($title) > $len) {
        $keys = array_keys(str_word_count($title, 2));
        $title = substr($title, 0, $keys[$len]);
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter('the_title', 'limit_word_count');
```

You can put any kind of limit on almost anything you like, you just need the correct filter